# Any dependence of Tomcat on Java JDK and JRE?

Tags: java, tomcat, eclipse-jdt

Could anybody give me a clear explanation on the dependence of Tomcat's JSP/Servlet engine on the JDK and JRE? Please correct me if my understanding (for Tomcat 9) is wrong:

- Tomcat currently uses Jasper 2 as its jsp engine, which is capable of coverting jsp into servlet (.java) and subsequently compiling servlet into byte code (.java). I figured out that Jasper 2 is using Eclipse's Eclipse JDT Java compiler, which is a stand-alone java compiler and has no dependence on JDK?
- Tomcat's servlet engine is actually using JRE as its runtime environment to run the compiled byte code. So Tomcat has to rely on the JRE we've installed on our computer? Then how do I ensure my installed JRE version is compatible with Tomcat's internal compiler (JDT), i.e., how do I determine the JDT compliance level to JDK?

Comment: By **looking** at the column labeled "Supported Java Versions" in [**this** handy table](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). As noted in the link, *Each version of Tomcat is supported for any stable Java release that meets the requirements of the final column in the table above.*

Comment: One additional cross check you may want to be mindful of is that the **Dynamic Web Module** version in the **Project Facets** of your web project maps to the **Servlet Spec** column in that table which Elliot linked to. So, for example, if your Dynamic Web Module version is 4.0 then you need a Tomcat version which supports Servlet 4.0, and the table shows that the only Tomcat version which does that currently is 9.